# how to pass two class instances to a method of the class in python

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, binary-tree

I made two trees in python with two different instances of the same class. I need to access the method in the class now with both the instances(roots) with which i created two trees.

```
# To create a tree from scratch
class node:
    """To create nodes each time an instance has been
    created"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def issame(self,root1,root2):
  if root1 or root2:
    print(root1.data,root2.data)
    self.issame(root1.left,root2.left)

"""To insert the data manually"""
##First Tree
root1 = node(10)
root1.left = node(20)
root1.right = node(30)
root1.left.left = node(50)

##Second Tree
root2 = node(20)
root2.left = node(20)
root2.right = node(30)
root2.left.left = node(50)

issame(root1,root2)
```

I read in some post that we can keep the **issame** function definition outside of the class and use self within. Now at the end if i call the function, it says `issame` doesn't exist. Issame is used to check if leaf nodes of tree are same and the method is not fully developed as i faced the problem in first step.

Comment: What is `issame` intended to do?

Comment: just a method to check if the leaf nodes are same. Full code for it has not been written yet as i faced the difficulty in first step

Comment: "I read in some post that we can keep the issame function definition outside of the class and use self within" I'm not entirely sure if I am interpreting this correctly, but if I am, but it sounds wrong, or at the very least, not advisable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008991/python-create-instance-of-class-in-another-class-with-generic-example

Answer (score 3):

You must choose whether you want `issame()` in the class, or outside, but it cannot be a hybrid of a little bit of both:

You must also override the `__eq__` method of your `Node` class in order to compare two nodes with the operator `==`

#### issame as a method:

```
class Node:
    """To create nodes each time an instance has been
    created"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, Node)
        return self.data == other.data \
               and self.left == other.left \
               and self.right == other.right

    def issame(self, root2):
      return self == root2

"""To insert the data manually"""
##First Tree
root1 = Node(10)
root1.left = Node(20)
root1.right = Node(30)
root1.left.left = Node(50)

##Second Tree
root2 = Node(20)
root2.left = Node(20)
root2.right = Node(30)
root2.left.left = Node(50)

root1.issame(root2)          #<-- here you are calling issame on root1, with root2 as argument
```

#### issame as a function:

```
class Node:
    """To create nodes each time an instance has been
    created"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, Node)
        return self.data == other.data \
               and self.left == other.left \
               and self.right == other.right

def issame(root1, root2):
    return root1 == root2

"""To insert the data manually"""
##First Tree
root1 = Node(10)
root1.left = Node(20)
root1.right = Node(30)
root1.left.left = Node(50)

##Second Tree
root2 = Node(20)
root2.left = Node(20)
root2.right = Node(30)
root2.left.left = Node(50)

issame(root1, root2)       # < attention, different way of calling
                           # here you are calling issame passing root 1 and root2 as arguments
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you trying to achieve with the __eq__ module here?

Comment: `__eq__` is the underlying operations behind the `==` operator. It is the operator that tests for equality. For complex objects, you must override it so equality is tested the way you intend it to be; if not, the memory address of the objects will be tested for equality, not the values, and not the children, or whatever else you are using to assert equality between two of your `Node` objects

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I need to comapre  the leaf values not the leaf objects for the two trees I passed.

Comment: Yes, that is what it does: Read the code, `__eq__` recursively calls `==` on the leaves to compare them; if they are all equal, it returns True, if not, False

Answer (score 2):

Try modify your issame method (outside class):

```
def issame(root1,root2):
   if root1 or root2:
   print(root1.data,root2.data)
       issame(root1.left,root2.left)
```

I got the below result:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
10 20
20 20
50 50
```

Full code:

```
# To create a tree from scratch
class node:
    """To create nodes each time an instance has been created"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def issame(roota,rootb):
   if roota or rootb:
      print(roota.data,rootb.data)
      issame(roota.left,rootb.left)

"""To insert the data manually"""
##First Tree
root1 = node(10)
root1.left = node(20)
root1.right = node(30)
root1.left.left = node(50)

##Second Tree
root2 = node(20)
root2.left = node(20)
root2.right = node(30)
root2.left.left = node(50)

issame(root1,root2)
```

Comment: done... you can also try @classmethod (http://www.pythoncentral.io/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python/) so you can make issame the method for the whole class (not instance)

Comment: He is trying to traverse the tree to leaf node then compare but not finish that part yet. For now he got stuck in the traverse part

Comment: That’s why I suggest him better use classmethod. So can cal method directly from class without instance to compare trees later